# Создание нескольких окон в Screen через bash скрипт

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

Нужно с помощью скрипта создать 3 окна screen, а в этих окнах запустить код. Важно что бы скрипт не ожидал пока код выполниться, а переходил к созданию нового окна screen и запуска в нем кода.

Так же нужно что бы процесс кода отображался, т.е. запускать его с nohup, & и т.п. в фоне - не подходит.

Я пробовал многие варианты имитации нажатия клавиш, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Вот что я сделал. В коде видно вопросы с которыми у меня возникли проблемы.

```
for (( i=0; i<3; i++ ))
do
if(i == 0)
then
screen -S start
else
#1)Как передать нажатие клавиш?
Ctrl+A потом c # — создать окно screen
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python
#2)Как Не дожидаясь пока выполнится эта команда, продолжить выполнение цикла.
fi
done
```

Comment: в tmux [можно](https://superuser.com/questions/492266/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session) что-то вроде этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в проекте *devstack* до начала 2017 года «полным ходом» использовалась программа *screen*.

вот этим коммитом всё связанное с ней было удалено: [Remove screen support from devstack completely](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/commit/cdba1b37).

из коммита можно почерпнуть полезные опции. я вот почерпнул и небольшой скриптик написал. для демонстрации в *screen*-е запускаются три окна. первое пустое, с оболочкой, во втором и третьем выполняется *sleep*:

```
# имя screen
sname=tryscreen

add_window() {
  name=$1
  cmd=$2

  # создание нового окна с указанным именем
  screen -r ${sname} -X screen -t ${name}
  # пауза нужна, чтобы оболочка успела нарисовать приглашение
  sleep 0.5
  # запустить команду в этом окне
  screen -r ${sname} -p ${name} -X stuff "$cmd$nl"
}

# символ 0d, оно же carriage return
nl=$(echo -ne '\015')

# создание нового screen
screen -c /dev/null -d -m -S ${sname} -t shell
# пауза на всякий случай (в devstack-е вообще три секунды)
sleep 0.5
# конфигурирование (взято из devstack-а)
hardstatus='%{= .} %-Lw%{= .}%> %n%f %t*%{= .}%+Lw%< %-=%{g}(%{d}%H/%l%{g})'
screen -r ${sname} -X hardstatus alwayslastline "$hardstatus"
screen -r ${sname} -X setenv PROMPT_COMMAND /bin/true

add_window "один" "sleep 15"
add_window "два"  "sleep 10"

# подключение к созданному screen с переключением на первое окно
screen -RD ${sname} -p 0
```

Comment: Это действительно работает. Большое спасибо.