# Автоматизация команды screen на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, gnu-screen

Есть скрипт, который я запускаю в разных **screen** с разными параметрами

```
screen ./script -S 8080
screen ./script -S 8081
```

Но я не знаю как мне автоматизировать работу со **screen**
Я хочу запускать новые screen или закрывать старые, в зависимости от запросов к серверу

Я пробовал использовать node js:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

var workerProcess = child_process.spawn('screen', ['./script -S 8080']);
 
workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {
   console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> stdout: Must be connected to a terminal.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/895303/178576

Comment: Вы пишите сервис? Ну так запускайте как сервис. В systemd это категорически просто. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html